# Angular PWA + nginx - fail to load the app on app version change

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, chromium, browser-cache

I have a problem with my angular (15) based app, which also contains PWA.
The problem occurs when I upgrade the app version.
When I open the app, it fails after tying to fetch `main.**.js` and `runtime.**.js`, which is ok, because these files do not longer exist, but the question is - why are they tried to be fetched "in front", without any fallback to the service worker, to check if there is something new on the server? The app just fails, the only way is to refresh the browser with cache reset.

But I cannot, because that app is served in embedded chromium, which do not expose refresh action, and `location.reload()` do not manage cache (yeah,`true` as a parameter... but let do not mention it). Also, it would require from the user manual action, which is a bit frustrating - you need to refresh the page, because our configuration is invalid (is not it?) and you will not use the app otherwise. As far as I know PWA should manage version udpate by itself.

Mentioning configuration, PWA config is a standard one for Angular, please find it below:

```json
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)",
          "/*.json"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In my main app component, I have also something like this

```
 if (this.swUpdate.isEnabled) {
      this.logger.log("Checking new version availability");
      this.swUpdate.checkForUpdate().then((v) => {
        if (v) {
          // we cannot update the app here because it can be used in many contexts;
          // the consumer may be not ready for these updates
          VersionAsserter.onNewVersionAvailable();
          this.logger.log("New app version available");
          this.openUpdateNeededNotification();
        } else {
          this.logger.log("No update available");
        }
      }).catch(e => {
        this.logger.error("Failed to check version update", e);
      });
    } else {
      this.logger.log("Service worker (PWA) is disabled");
    }
```

That `VersionAsserter` has inside indeed `document.location.reload()`, but ...

1. it will not trigger, because `main` cannot be loaded, and I just have error with that :)
2. if it was loaded (I had cases when it loaded old version even after update) it did not return any info that the new app is available.

So far I noticed that when I open the app second time, it loads a new version, but this is not the best to tell the user that they must... open it again. What if it will not work (it also happened, I assume that it downloads a new version in the background)?.

I also managed to return a clean up script in my nginx, which is forcing a clean up; it contains service worker clean up, then reload the whole page. Also, when returning it contains the only way I have found, to reset the site cache - by including `Clear-Site-Data: "cache"` header.

Any idea how to make it reliable, and to prevent the whole service worker clean up, same as the cache of other files? I have lots of images, quite often used, which do not change and are fetched from the server. And they do no change, but when I use that header, these are purged...